Is there a jdbc-driver to fetch DB credentials from Azure-Key-Vault?
AWS has a library that provides wrappers for common jdbc drivers that you can specify while configuring a DataSource resource (in server.xml say) and introduce zero code changes. I'm specifically referring to this aws library: aws-secretsmanager-jdbc. At application runtime (specifically when a connection is requested) the wrapper driver dynamically fetches username/password from AWS Secrets Manager and injects it into the DataSource.
Is there a similar wrapper driver I can use in Azure deployments? That, at connection time fetches username/password from Azure Key Vault?
I'm trying to deploy the same application to Azure that I already have on AWS and ideally I would specify the Azure equivalent of aws-secretsmanager-jdbc wrapper driver in a config file and everything would work without any code changes to my application. If such a library does not exist for Azure, I will have to modify application code to deal with API calls to AKV and so on (is my understanding).
My search* didn't yield results I was looking for. Just before I give up, thought to check if others have figured out a solution in a different way??

*I have googled 'azure key vault jdbc library' and looked at the top 10 or so hits.


As of now, there is no direct JDBC driver available to fetch database credentials directly from Azure Key Vault.
However, you can achieve the same requirement by using below approach to fetch database credentials from Azure Key Vault, refer my SO answer.
pom.xml:
<properties>
       <java.version>8</java.version>
       <version.spring.cloud.azure>4.5.0</version.spring.cloud.azure>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
               <version>${version.spring.cloud.azure}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

KeyVaultController.java:
package com.myapp.keyvault.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class KeyVaultController {

   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   private String connectionString;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
   private String dbuser;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
   private String dbpass;

   @GetMapping("/getsecret")
   public String get() {
       System.out.println("\nYour Stored Secret Key is " + connectionString + " " + dbuser + " " + dbpass);
       return "Your Stored Secret Key is " + connectionString + " " + dbuser + " " + dbpass;
   }
}

application.properties:
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=client_secret
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=keyvault_url
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=tenant_id

Output:


Does this library fetch the secret only once over the duration of the application's lifetime or is there a caching/refreshing the cache mechanism happening behind the scenes?

You can make multiple requests to Azure Key Vault using the client library and fetch the credentials whenever required within your application.

Obviously I can do that. I was asking whether this library takes care of it under the hood or not. Sorry, this was not helpful

What is the point of downvoting my question? There is literally no other question like it. And it is pretty clear - I wanted to know if a certain azure library  - akin to a specified aws library - exists or not.
The answers I received are about Spring and my application is not a Spring app.
This is just abuse of power.
P.S. I went with API calls to Azure, and building my own cache (aws-jdbc-secretsmanager library comes built in with a SecretCache) but it was significantly more work which I wanted to avoid if possible.
